# How to set breakpoints in windbg that does not stop the execution of the program just logs the function called

Tags: windbg, breakpoints

I am debugging a windows component and want to view all the functions of a particular *dll* that are called (also in the exact order they are called). I can do this by attaching the component to ***windbg*** and setting breakpoints over all the exported functions (`bm *module_name!*`) of the *dll* in question.

This works as expected. Whenever an exported function of that *dll* is called windbg breaks the execution and prints on the screen information about the breakpoint that is hit. After that I can manually resume execution by pressing *F5* or giving the go command.

**The problem:**
Some functions of the dll have to return very quickly (immediately) else the component crashes. In that case the breakpoint causes the component to crash. I can remove the breakpoint in question but then there would be no log of it being hit.

I looked around and found that I can run a command whenever a breakpoint is hit. `bm module_name!func_name ".printf \"func_name\n\";gc"` But this is not feasible for every exported function. The *dll* has about a few 100 exported functions.

**What can I do to log (on the screen itself) every exported function that is hit (even the breakpoint number would do if nothing else can be done). Is there a variable name I can use in the `printf` command that can print the function name (or the breakpoint number if not the function name)?**

Comment: What is the problem here, you want a list of the functions being hit and then continue but remove the breakpoints or are you wanting to just output the first line of the call stack? You could try `.kframes=1;bm *modulename!* "kb;gc"`, this will set the call stack to 1, for every breakpoint hit it will dump just the first call which will be the function hit but you will get a lot of hits though

Comment: `Numeric expression missing from '=1;bm *modulename!* "kb;gc"'`

Comment: FTR: I dont want to remove the breakpoint.

Comment: sorry do you just want to dump the call stack for every breakpoint hit, the command string `"kb;gc"` will do that, if this is too verbose and you just want the function name then `.kframes=0n1` will set the call stack depth to 1, sorry I had a typo in my original comment

Comment: Still doesn't work. Same error. When and where do I type in `.kframes=0n1` ?

Comment: what doesn't work specifically?

Comment: You call `.kframes=0n1` before you enter the command to set the breakpoints

Comment: OK I see where I went wrong `.kframes 1` sets the call stack to a depth of 1, this will reduce the verbosity of the call stacks being displayed

Comment: The `k` commands actually take a count argument, so you don't necessarily need to run `.kframes` first: `bm blah "k 1;gc"`

Comment: @KurtHutchinson Where in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff538903(v=vs.85).aspx) is this stated? Is this a hidden feature (wouldn't surprise me) but I wasn't aware of this

Comment: @EdChum It's documented: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551943.aspx. `FrameCount: Specifies the number of stack frames to display.`

Comment: @KurtHutchinson thanks for the link was looking in wrong place, never used it so wasn't aware

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out. Thanks to EdChum.

The command: `bm *module_name!* ".frame;gc"`

Comment: how did you get around the 32 breakpoint limit ? "You have attempted to enable XX KD breakpoints, which exceeds the currently supported limit of 32 breakpoints for Windows kernel debugging. Breakpoints exceeding this limit are ignored"

Comment: Fortunately/Unfortunately the component I was debugging had no such limits. And I don't have a windows machine anymore to try things out. I think it would serve you better to ask a new question. Good luck!

Comment: I'm guessing thats a user mode application, perhaps there is no such limits there.

Comment: It wasn't. It was `spoolsv.exe` which runs as the `system` user, IIRC.

Comment: Executable are user mode. Kernel mode would be .sys drivers / core OS :)

Comment: Oh well, TIL. Thanks.